# What does "int" mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript, int

I've been asked by my teacher to do a javascript function that reverses an integer number (eg. 321->123) and uses

```
int reverse(int n){ }
```

I am not sure what is the "int" in the script. Can somebody explain it to me? I don't want a whole script, I just need to understand what does the "int" do. I have tried to do

```
int reverse(int n) {
n=parseInt(prompt('Podaj liczbę'))
    for(var r=0 n; n=Math.floor(n/10)) {
        r *= 10
        r += n % 10
    }
    document.write(r) 
}
```

but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps he meant a different language?!?

Comment: This isn't valid JavaScript. It has other errors besides `int`.

Comment: I think he only meant to specify that the function must accept an integer as argument and must return an integer.

Comment: `int reverse(int n){ }` looks suspiciously like [Java](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/integer_reverse.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Fabrizio Calderan's comment is spot-on.

You might want to break down your code into parts:

```
var reverse = function(n) {
    // your reversal code.
}

var n = parseInt(prompt('Podaj liczbę'));
var r = reverse(n);

alert("Reversed: " + r);
```

I would suggest that you don't use `document.write` here.

Comment: why `document.write` is not suggested by most of the peoples like you...? could you please explain that...

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @KendallFrey: It started as a comment and grew too large.  :-)  I actually deleted the comment, because it didn't make sense there.  Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I think i will stay with it. You helped me alot, thank you!

Comment: @CJRamki: `document.write` has very limited use.  It's only useful when you're first loading the page, so often doesn't work well alongside a `prompt`.  There are reasonable techniques to add to an existing DOM, and they're not hard to use, but for simple one-off displays, an `alert` or `console.log` is usually fine and won't confuse people when it doesn't show up, the way `document.write` often doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is dynamically typed, so `int reverse(int n){ }` isn't proper Javascript.

Probably your teacher was giving you an indication about what your function should use as an argument and as return type, ie she meant:

> Write a Javascript function called `reverse` that takes an integer as an argument an returns an integer.

Comment: Proper way to declare such a method would be **function reverse(n) {** instead of **int reverse(int n) {**

Comment: Or maybe the teacher didn't say JavaScript at all...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working javascript version of this function

```
function reverse(n) {
  n=parseInt(prompt('Podaj liczbę'))
  var res = o
   for(var r=0; n=Math.floor(n/10);r++) {
    res *= 10
    res += n % 10
   }
  alert(res)
}

reverse(10)
```

Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/r8Wwf/